# Waiting until onReceive runs and stop

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

**Main Purpose:
Reading an access point's properties freshly, and use it.**

I tried to add a custom BroadcastReceiver class to my activity.

If it is true; I learned that; `onReceive` runs after intent action, 
(here: `WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`).

But i think i must wait until `onReceive` finishes running to get a fresh r11.

When i debug the method "useResults"; "use r11, modify r11" lines runs first, after a while `onReceive` starts to run.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener{

    int r11=0;


    public void useResults(){

             mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

             receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
             registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter( WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            mainWifi.startScan();

             //use r11
             //modify r11
             //do something with r11

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(
                    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            super.onResume();
        }

        class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
                for (ScanResult result0:wifiList) {
                    String ssid0 = result0.SSID;



                    if(ssid0.compareTo("anID")==0){

                        r11=result0.level;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: As your `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class of your `Activity`, it can call methods in the `Activity` itself. There's no need to wait, just make the last thing you do in the `onReceive(...)` method is call the `Activity` method which needs the result.

Comment: @Squonk thanks but i need to ask. Is it appropriate to do something in useResults then fork to onReceive and continue and finish all the rest application logic in onReceive?  I think there must be there should be a cleaner way?

Comment: You don't call the `onReceive` method of a `BroadcastReceiver` - that's done automatically by the system when whatever your `BroadcastReceiver` is listening for gets broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BroadcastReceiver` is an inner class, there's nothing wrong or dirty in using it to call methods on the class. That's what inner classes are for.

Just create a separate method

```
void doR11Results(){
         //use r11
         //modify r11
         //do something with r11
}
```

... and call it from `onReceive`. Super simple!